# trouble in formatting text with tr

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the text in the following format

```
line 1,
line 2,
< Blank line >
line 3,
line 4,
< Blank line >
line 5,
line 4,
< Blank line >
```

I need to put it in the format:

```
line 1,line 2,
< Blank line >
line 3,line 4,
< Blank line >
line 5,line 4,
< Blank line >
```

So I'm trying:

```
tr -d '\n' < myfile.txt > myfile_res.txt
```

But then I get all concatenated:

```
line 1,line 2,line 3,line 4,line 5,line 4
```

What I need is to remove '\n' only from lines containing characters and leave the blank lines and I believe it will work.

Any idea how to encode this?

Comment: Are all non-blank lines of the input file guaranteed to end with a `,` (comma)?

Answer (score 2):

`tr` only looks at one character at a time, so it doesn't really work when you need to check the context.

Since the sections are separated by empty lines, the paragraph mode of `awk` fits nicely:

```
awk -vRS= '{gsub(/\n/, ""); print $0 "\n"}' myfile.txt
```

Setting `RS` empty loads "records" separated by empty lines, and for each record we again remove the newlines, and then print the record with an extra newline.

Similarly in Perl, though with two extra newlines here because Perl does load the final newline like any other character:

```
perl -00ne 's/\n//g; print "$_\n\n"' myfile.txt
```

Both of those will treat multiple blank lines the same as one.

---

We could do this with sed, but it's a bit hairier than my original attempt if we need to support blocks of more than two lines.

```
sed -n 'H; $bL; /./d; :L; x; s/\n//g; s/$/\n/; p;' myfile.txt
```

Append the current line to the hold buffer (`H`), then check if this is the last line (`$`), in which case branch to L (`bL`). If not, check if there are any characters (`/./`), and if so, delete (`d`) the line and go back to start.

Otherwise (the line is empty), fall through to `L`, where we swap (`x`) the hold buffer and the current line (pattern space), remove newlines (`s/\n//g`), add another to the end (`s/$/\n/`) and implicitly print the pattern space, now containing the lines we collected since the previous blank line. Here, extra blank lines will produce more extra blank lines.

Comment: ikkachu, Thank you for the detailed explanation. the awk -vRS= '{gsub(/\n/, ""); print $0 "\n"}' myfile.txt

Comment: awk -vRS= '{gsub(/\n/, ""); print $0 "\n"}' myfile.txt  works perfectly well in my case.   Thank you again !

Answer (score 1):

You can use this sed command

```
sed '/,/{N;s/\n//;s/$//;}' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I noticed It works pretty well in case you only have 2 lines interrupted by a blank line. In case you have 3 lines it leaves the 3rd line bellow the 2nd one.